# I can't get my javascript to change text on a page

Tags: javascript, html

Edit2 : A friend informed me that I forgot to mention that this script would load through Greasemonkey

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and I'm trying to self teach it.

I've been trying to get text on a page to change using this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("gamepage_header").innerHTML = '<h1>Test</h1>'
```

Instead of doing what I want, it seems to just sit there and do nothing.
Yes, I've looked in many places to something to work.

Thanks

Edit:
This is the page I'm trying to edit. http://www.kongregate.com/games/kChamp/shellshock-live
My real idea is to fetch a link within the HTML, then set the gamepage_header as the link so I can simply rightclick and download the .swf.

As per request, here is my whole "code", if you can call it that.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SWFLinkage for KH
// @namespace   tag://kongregate
// @description SWF Link getter
// @version     1
// @grant           none
// @author          SimpleAOB
// @date            12.7.2012
// ==/UserScript==
document.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("gamepage_header").innerHTML = '<h1>Test</h1>' 
};
```

Comment: Are you running the code before the document has loaded that element? The code works just fine if you run it on DOM ready. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/KVxF9/

Comment: read Douglas Crockfords 'Javascript the good parts' http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596517742/wrrrldwideweb then watch his videos, then go to the jquery website.  http://jquery.com/

Comment: More broadly -- have you learned to use your browser's error console?

Comment: Please post your entire code example since what you posted above works fine in the proper context.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Ball's comment revealed that you need to wait until the page loads.

The code may be running before `gamepage_header` is loaded. To resolve this, use:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Code goes here.
};
```

This waits until the page loads, then runs the code. Don't worry about the syntax; you will learn soon enough as you gain more skill in JS.

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure the page has loaded before running your script as you are trying to access the DOM before it has completely loaded, whether you add the script in the head or before your'e closing body tag is up to you, but adding before your closing body tag will have a miniscule performance improvement, regardless as long as it's wrapped in `window.onload = function(){};`, your good to go.

### http://jsfiddle.net/G58KY/

from your edit you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/YsnJv/
specify which link you are trying to access as "link" most likeyly will not work unless by some chance the link has the same id

```
window.onload = function () {
    var link = document.getElementById("link").href;
    document.getElementById("gamepage_header").innerHTML = '<h1><a href="'+link+'">Test</a></h1>';
}
```